# How to format time input as "mm:ss" without JavaScript

Tags: html, css, html-input

I am trying to format the time input as "mm:ss" format instead of the default "hh:mm" format. I have read the document about [Time Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) but I still don't know how to change its format.

Is there any way to change the time input format without using JavaScript?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: In the docs, it specifies: "If the time includes seconds (see Using the step attribute), the format is always hh:mm:ss" [at the time value format section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#time_value_format).

Comment: Given the differing user interfaces provided by various browsers plus the fact that hh is always included I can't see how you can do this using time input. I think you'd have to implement your own version (and that will ultimately require a bit of JS).

Comment: @PhanDC did you find or come up with a solution for this problem?

Comment: @AGB sorry for my late response. I didnot find any solutions. Then I decided to make my own component. I used a input tag and wrote some keyboard rules to force user enter "mm:ss" format.

Comment: @PhanDC thanks, any chance you could post that as an answer?

Comment: @AGB Well, I think it's quite a dummy code. I will post it here if you want.